# Не могу вставить значение состояния ToggleButton в SQLite

Tags: java, android

Не могу ввести значения состояния `ToggleButton` в таблицу. AndroidStudio ругается на строку:

```
tbGender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Помогите пожалуйста с этим разобраться. Всё, что я делаю, Студия подчеркивает красным или выбрасывает как неиспользуемое

```
package ru.bimradio.translation.fragments;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import ru.bimradio.translation.R;
import ru.lovetatar_media_group.auth.DatabaseHelper;


public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    DatabaseHelper bim_db;
    Button btnAddData;
    EditText etName, etDate;
    ToggleButton tbGender;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile,
                container, false);
        bim_db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        etName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNewName);
        etDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNewDate);
        btnAddData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddData);
        ToggleButton tbGender = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.tbNewGender);
        AddData();
        return view;
    }

    public void AddData() {
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String date = etDate.getText().toString();
                final  String gender = null;
                final ToggleButton tbGender = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.tbNewGender);
                tbGender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if(tbGender.isChecked())
                        {
                            String gender = "male";
                        }
                        else {
                            String gender = "female";
                        }

                    }
                });


                boolean insertData = bim_db.addData(name, date, gender);

                if (insertData == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Данные аккаунта успешно сохранены!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Что-то пошло не так :(.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Покажите текст ошибки и переведите название вопроса на русский! )

Comment: `if (insertData == true) {` - ... шикарно

Answer (score 3):

Вместо

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

   ToggleButton tbGender = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.tbNewGender);

}
```

надо

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

 ...

 final ToggleButton tbGender;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

    tbGender = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.tbNewGender);

}
```

Сейчас вы создаете локальный объект `tbGender`, который имеет видимость только внутри метода `onCreateView()`, в то время, как одноименное поле класса `tbGender` остается не проинициализированным и обращения к нему в дальнейшем (в слушателе) приведут к ошибке.

Из метода `onClick()` это надо убрать вовсе:

```
final ToggleButton tbGender = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.tbNewGender);
```

чтобы было так (в переданном в слушатель `View` только кнопка и в ней невозможно найти какой-либо переключатель) :

```
public void AddData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name = etName.getText().toString();
            String date = etDate.getText().toString();
            final  String gender = null;
            tbGender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Вы каждый раз создаете новый объект переключателя (конструкция языка с указанием типа объекта - `ToggleButton tbGender` каждый раз создает новый объект) , в то время, как вам надо один раз проинициализировать поле класса и в дальнейшем работать только с ним, обращаясь к нему по имени (без указания типа).

Кроме того, экземпляры, которые передаются в анонимные классы (вы создаете анонимный класс слушателя) должны иметь модификатор `final`, иначе их передача будет невозможна.

Comment: Теперь уже приложение ругается и вылетает на строке     ` boolean insertData = bim_db.addData(name, date, gender);`

Comment: @LoveTatar Если у вас другая проблема, которую вы не можете решить самостоятельно, задайте новый вопрос, перед этим настоятельно рекомендую прочитать, как здесь [правильно задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить на них полезный ответ. В частности, описание проблемы - "оно ругается.." никак не поможет решить ее.